# Run blender Still rendering from command line with external Python script

Tags: python, rendering

first of all, thanks for the help you have provided me indirectly through this forum.

I am trying to generate still pictures using blender. I have the python script and the model which are both functioning well but i would like to take the script out of the blender file to be able to generate it with an external macro.

I can currently generate the picture by running the python script from the GUI. I am also able to generate the picture from the command line if I call the script saved within the blender file (Internal_Script.py is inside the blender file).:
"C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\blender.exe" --background model.blend --python Internal_Script.py  -f 1

however, if I take the content of this script and copy it in a file alongside the blend file, it doesn't work any more (External_Script.py is a separate file now).
"C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\blender.exe" --background model.blend --python External_Script.py  -f 1

the python script is definitely being read as i get an error if I misspell the filename.

```
Error: Cannot render, no camera
```

This is quite strange as there is definitely a camera and the script works just fine if it's saved in the blender file.

Would you have any idea about what's going on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check that `bpy.context.scene.camera` is set to your newly added camera. That property determines which camera is used for rendering, and if it's still `None` it won't work.

Comment: hi, thanks for your response, I believe that I'm already doing this but using -f rather than the full --render-frame syntax. The reason I need the script is because I am generating the whole model/mesh with python. The blend file contains the materials I an using.

Comment: Doh! Of course.

Have you tried removing the --background option, so that you can see what's going on?

Comment: if I remove background, the blender window starts but I get the same error.

Comment: I ran it with --debug-all to get more info and the issue seems to be related to the fact that the code deletes the existing camera and creates a new one.   I do this as I clear the whole model before I start creating the new mesh. What is strange is that the camera seems to be created, but blender then says that there is no camera...

Comment: Then why remove & recreate the same camera? Why not set its properties such that it's correct, and always use the same camera object?

Alternatively, check that `bpy.context.scene.camera` is set to your newly added camera. That property determines which camera is used for rendering, and if it's still `None` it won't work.

Comment: yes, that was it, I was missing bpy.context.scene.camera = bpy.context.object

Comment: Great! I've updated my answer, please upvote & mark as "answer".

Comment: I can't upvote because I haven't got 15 "reputations" yet but I support your response!

Comment: I've upvoted your question, hopefully that'll give you some more rep ;-)

Comment: @hyg53 still waiting for that upvote :)